# How to write php in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a java-script function. now want to print my php variable in this javascript

My code:

```
<?php
$likn='www.mysite.com';

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

function fnFormatDetails ( oTable, nTr )
{
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );
    var sOut = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Rendering engine:</td><td>'+aData[1]+' '+aData[4]+'</td></tr>';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Link to source:</td><td><?php print''.$link.'';  ?></td></tr>';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Extra info:</td><td>And any further details here (images etc)</td></tr>';
    sOut += '</table>';

    return sOut;
}




</script>
```

I wrote this code but it did not work as expected:
 `<td>Link to source:</td><td><?php print''.$link.'';  ?></td>`

Comment: Have you saved this in a .php file?

Comment: if this is a php file, your php code have to be out of quotes in order to be processed by php

Answer (score 2):

try following line instead,

`sOut += '<tr><td>Link to source:</td><td><?php echo $likn;  ?></td></tr>';`

you store your PHP value in different variable and going to access with the different variable name.

PHP variable: $likn
in javascript you are using: $links

So correct it first.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
sOut += "<tr><td>Rendering engine:</td><td>'+aData[1]+' '+aData[4]+'</td></tr>";
    sOut += "<tr><td>Link to source:</td><td><?php print''.$link.'';  ?></td></tr>";
    sOut += "<tr><td>Extra info:</td><td>And any further details here (images etc)</td></tr>";
    sOut += "</table>";
```

to escape single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

your php code has to be out of quotes so php can process it, this might be you solution:

```
<?php
$likn='www.mysite.com';

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

function fnFormatDetails ( oTable, nTr )
{
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );
    var sOut = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Rendering engine:</td><td>'+aData[1]+' '+aData[4]+'</td></tr>';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Link to source:</td><td>' + <?php print $link; ?> + '</td></tr>';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Extra info:</td><td>And any further details here (images etc)</td></tr>';
    sOut += '</table>';

    return sOut;
}




</script>
```

Comment: Detection of Processing Instructions such as <?php ?> does not care for quotes used in sequences of PCDATA ...